# Sort dict values to decending order in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this.

```
d = {'"mn': '800"', '"kl': '700"', '"ng': '1100"'}
```

How to sort this into descending order. like below

```
ng,1100

mn,800

kl,700
```

Comment: As an aside, where did that dictionary come from?  There are quotation marks on the left of each key, and on the right of each value, which makes it feel like the source was parsed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can user OrderedDict for that.

```
reverse_dictionary = OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(d.items())), key=lambda t: t[1])
```

Comment: Can you share the code.

Comment: reverse_dictionary = OrderedDict(reversed(sorted(d.items())), key=lambda t: t[1])

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean, a dictionary by definition is unsorted. you may want to use an array of dictionaries.